# How to package the gtk# dependency with the executable

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk#

I am working on a game for an assignment for my college courses and am being forced, essentially, to use C#, so on my laptop I am using Monodevelop with Debian Linux. Trouble is that GTK# apps won't run on Windows unless the dependencies are installed, which is a problem as my Uni's computers don't have that.

My question is this, is there a way to package the dependencies with my compiled executable so I don't have to worry about having that stuff installed? Using Visual C# is essentially out of the question as this laptop barely can run Debian let alone Windows. I am aware of the System.Windows.Forms namespace, but for some reason my version of Monodevelop did not come with that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, MonoDevelop does not have a Winforms *designer*. You can use winForms, though only by code, and Mono's support is quite low.

Answer (score 1):

Debian splits up Mono into many smaller packages. I believe the one for System.Windows.Forms is called `libmono-winforms2.0-cil`.

You could bundle GTK# with your app but it would be complicated. You'd have to include all the GTK# and GTK+ libraries in the same directory as your app.

Comment: Is there a list of those somewhere? I am willing to do that.

Comment: Look in C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12. The files are all installed there. You'll have to look up the Windows loading path rules for native and managed libraries for work out how to put it alongside your app. I think in general things will be loaded from your app's dir first, so you could just try adding stuff every time you run into an error, until it works...